# airbnb mashape api not working in php

Tags: php, ajax, json, api, curl

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$("#btnTrigger").on('click',function(){ 

$.ajax({

      url:'https://airbnb.p.mashape.com/s', 
     type:'Get', 
    data:{location:$("boxArea").val()}, 
    datatype:'json', 
    success:function(data) {
     alert(JSON.stringify(data)); 
    $("#boxArea").val(JSON.stringify(data));
 },

    error:function(err)
   { 
 alert(err);  
}, 

      beforeSend:function(Xhr) { 

            Xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization","7MooPcOHR9mshGWoRGqd4h4UMv2Cp1kFLV3jsn3UDWi3yIxSot");
 } 
});
 });
 });
```

as this is working fine on js fiddle but not working when i run in php.....kindly help about how to generate api of airbnb.com and use it in php

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting?
Can you link to the API of AIRBNB? 
I don't think it exists anymore thus why you're getting erorrs